# Hard definite integral. Does it have a closed form?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Could someone help me with this integral? $$ \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\log \left(\frac{1-y z}{\sqrt{y^2-2 y z+1}}+1\right)}{\sqrt{y^2-2 y z+1}} \, dy$$
with $|z|<1$.

I've tried all methods known... Trigonometric substitutions doesn't work, neither the change of variables $ u = y^2-2 y z+1 $, etc. I also tried using complex integration, but the problem is that the poles are at $ y = z + i \sqrt{1-z^2}$, so they lie on the unit circle.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your work and indicate where do you stuck ?

Comment: You may need to separately consider $|z|<1, \, |z|=1, \, |z|>1$.

Comment: For $z=0$: $\frac{1}{4} \left(\pi ^2-2 \left(\text{Li}_2\left(17-12 \sqrt{2}\right)-6
   \text{Li}_2\left(3-2 \sqrt{2}\right)+8
   \text{Li}_2\left(-1+\sqrt{2}\right)\right)\right)$. Yikes!

Comment: @J.G. sorry, I forgot to add |z| < 1

Comment: What makes you think this integral should have an expression in terms of elementary functions? It looks excruciating.

Comment: @TedShifrin That integral would be the result from the sum $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P_{n}(z) \frac{H(n)}{n+1}$$, where $P_n (z)$ are legendre polynomials and $H(n)$ are harmonic numbers.

Answer (score 2):

---

Define the function $\mathcal{I}:\left(-1,1\right)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ via the definite integral

$$\mathcal{I}{\left(p\right)}:=\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+\frac{1-px}{\sqrt{x^{2}-2px+1}}\right)}}{\sqrt{x^{2}-2px+1}}.\tag{1}$$

Note: Given fixed but arbitrary $p\in\left(-1,1\right)$, it's relatively easy to show that

$$\forall x\in\left[-1,1\right]:0<1-px\land0<x^{2}-2px+1,$$

so the RHS of $(1)$ above is a proper integral.

Recalling the definition of the real dilogarithm as

$$\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(z\right)}:=-\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-x\right)}}{x};~~~\small{z\in\left(-\infty,1\right]},\tag{2}$$

we obtain a closed-form expression for $\mathcal{I}$ in terms of the dilogarithm and elementary functions.

---

Suppose $p\in\left(-1,1\right)$. Using the Euler substitution $-x+\sqrt{x^{2}-2px+1}=t$, we have

$$x=\frac{1-t^{2}}{2\left(p+t\right)}\implies dx=dt\,\frac{(-1)\left(1+2pt+t^{2}\right)}{2\left(p+t\right)^{2}},$$

$$\sqrt{x^{2}-2px+1}=x+t=\frac{\left(1+2pt+t^{2}\right)}{2\left(p+t\right)},$$

and then,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(p\right)}
&=\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+\frac{1-px}{\sqrt{x^{2}-2px+1}}\right)}}{\sqrt{x^{2}-2px+1}}\\
&=\int_{1+\sqrt{2+2p}}^{-1+\sqrt{2-2p}}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{(-1)\left(1+2pt+t^{2}\right)}{2\left(p+t\right)^{2}}\cdot\frac{2\left(p+t\right)}{\left(1+2pt+t^{2}\right)}\\
&~~~~~\times\ln{\left(1+\frac{2\left(p+t\right)}{1+2pt+t^{2}}\cdot\frac{p+2t+pt^{2}}{2\left(p+t\right)}\right)};~~~\small{\left[x=\frac{1-t^{2}}{2\left(p+t\right)}\right]}\\
&=\int_{-1+\sqrt{2-2p}}^{1+\sqrt{2+2p}}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{\left(p+t\right)}\ln{\left(1+\frac{p+2t+pt^{2}}{1+2pt+t^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{-1+\sqrt{2(1-p)}}^{1+\sqrt{2(1+p)}}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{\left(p+t\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1+p\right)\left(1+t\right)^{2}}{1+2pt+t^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{-1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p}}^{1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+p}}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+p\right)}+2\ln{\left(1+t\right)}-\ln{\left(1+2pt+t^{2}\right)}}{p+t}\\
&=\int_{p-1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p}}^{p+1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+p}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+p\right)}+2\ln{\left(1-p+u\right)}-\ln{\left(1-p^{2}+u^{2}\right)}}{u};~~~\small{\left[t=u-p\right]}.\\
\end{align}$$

Observe that $0<p-1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p}<p+1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+p}$. We then obtain the following result:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(p\right)}
&=\int_{p-1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p}}^{p+1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+p}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+p\right)}+2\ln{\left(1-p+u\right)}-\ln{\left(1-p^{2}+u^{2}\right)}}{u}\\
&=\int_{p-1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p}}^{p+1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+p}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2\ln{\left(\frac{1-p+u}{1-p}\right)}-\ln{\left(\frac{1-p^{2}+u^{2}}{1-p^{2}}\right)}+\ln{\left(1-p\right)}}{u}\\
&=\int_{p-1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p}}^{p+1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+p}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2\ln{\left(\frac{1-p+u}{1-p}\right)}}{u}-\int_{p-1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p}}^{p+1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+p}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{1-p^{2}+u^{2}}{1-p^{2}}\right)}}{u}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{p-1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p}}^{p+1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+p}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-p\right)}}{u}\\
&=\int_{\frac{p-1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p}}{1-p}}^{\frac{p+1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+p}}{1-p}}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{2\ln{\left(1+v\right)}}{v};~~~\small{\left[u=(1-p)v\right]}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{\left(p-1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p}\right)^{2}}^{\left(p+1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+p}\right)^{2}}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{1-p^{2}+v}{1-p^{2}}\right)}}{2v};~~~\small{\left[u^{2}=v\right]}\\
&~~~~~+\ln{\left(1-p\right)}\int_{p-1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p}}^{p+1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+p}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{1}{u}\\
&=\int_{-\frac{p-1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p}}{1-p}}^{-\frac{p+1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+p}}{1-p}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2\ln{\left(1-x\right)}}{x};~~~\small{\left[v=-x\right]}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{\frac{\left(p-1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p}\right)^{2}}{1-p^{2}}}^{\frac{\left(p+1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+p}\right)^{2}}{1-p^{2}}}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+w\right)}}{2w};~~~\small{\left[v=(1-p^{2})w\right]}\\
&~~~~~+\ln{\left(1-p\right)}\left[\ln{\left(p+1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+p}\right)}-\ln{\left(p-1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p}\right)}\right]\\
&=2\int_{-\frac{p+1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+p}}{1-p}}^{-\frac{p-1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p}}{1-p}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{(-1)\ln{\left(1-x\right)}}{x}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{-\frac{\left(p+1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+p}\right)^{2}}{1-p^{2}}}^{-\frac{\left(p-1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p}\right)^{2}}{1-p^{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{(-1)\ln{\left(1-x\right)}}{x};~~~\small{\left[w=-x\right]}\\
&~~~~~+\ln{\left(1-p\right)}\left[\ln{\left(p+1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+p}\right)}-\ln{\left(p-1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p}\right)}\right]\\
&=2\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-\frac{p-1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p}}{1-p}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-\frac{p+1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+p}}{1-p}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-\frac{\left(p-1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p}\right)^{2}}{1-p^{2}}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-\frac{\left(p+1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+p}\right)^{2}}{1-p^{2}}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\ln{\left(1-p\right)}\left[\ln{\left(p+1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+p}\right)}-\ln{\left(p-1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p}\right)}\right]\\
&=2\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{1-p-\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p}}{1-p}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-\frac{1+p+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+p}}{1-p}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-\frac{\left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1-p}\right)^{2}}{1+p}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-\frac{\left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{1+p}\right)^{2}}{1-p}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\ln{\left(1-p\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{p+1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+p}}{p-1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p}}\right)}.\tag{3}\\
\end{align}$$

---

Comment: Genius!! Thanks!!